# how to display message dailogue in PCL project class file

Tags: xamarin, code-behind, messagebox, shared

I want to try display message dialogue in .cs file that is in pcl project.I want to call its method from my view.xaml.cs for displaying alert.

i tried to use

```
   var dialog = new MessageDialog(e.Message, e.GetType().ToString());
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ok", null));

        await dialog.ShowDialogSafely();
```

but that require windows.UI.Popups namespace that is not available in class file of pcl project.I think its because it shared by all platform and that namespace is for windows only.then how can I achieve this.please help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the User dialogs Plugin to achieve this. It provides cross platform dialogs. https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs. And then it's just a one liner:

```cs
await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync(e.Message, e.GetType().ToString());
```

You can install it via NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/. Please read the github readme on how to set it up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

AcrUserDialogs library allows using dialogs in PCL  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable without third-party plug-ins. Xamarin.Forms has it implemented:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/pop-ups/#Displaying_an_Alert

A simple informative MessageBox as follows:

```
DisplayAlert ("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
```

A window with more than 1 option like so:

```
var answer = await DisplayAlert ("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
```

Answer (score -1):

Replacement for [Acr.UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/) which worked for me is:

```
 var result = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
        title,
        message,
        buttonConfirmText,
        buttonCancelText);
```

Good side is because you don't need Plugin reference in the project either the 'UserDialogs.Init(this);' in your MainActivity class. One possibility is also with Prism but you need to install it: https://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Xamarin-Forms/4-Page-Dialog-Service/

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48009/pop-display-alert-message-from-viewmodel